# Use Win10 Image on a new hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-installation

First off, thanks in advance, and please let me know if I left anything out.

Several months ago, I bought a small SSD for the computer I was building. Needless to say, 128GB wasn't enough. Thankfully, just after installing several key applications, I made a system image and saved it to an external harddrive. I don't recall the exact instructions I used, but I can only assume it was the same as [these here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-revive-your-windows-10-installation-with-system-image-recovery/). However, this website doesn't quite answer my question about how to reapply the image.

So now I have a 128GB SSD I don't want anymore, a new 512GB SSD, and an external harddrive with the (70 some GB) image on it.

I do still have my Windows10 disc, so worst case scenario I can just do a fresh install (or install then apply the image). However, is there a way to not need the disc at all, or is that the point of the image, being that you do need the disc?

Comment: Most of the time a windows image can only be restored to the same drive. It embeds a drive signature and will not restore to a different drive, so do a clean install and reinstall all software. There may be software like Acronis that can convert the Windows backup image to their format and then restore it. Acronis could do this on earlier versions, not sure if they still do this with current versions.

Comment: Alright, didn't want to have to, but guess there is no choice haha. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Does the 128 GB hard drive still have the Windows on it, or you cleaned that after creating the image? Because you can use a variety of cloning and imaging software (not Windows') to copy a Windows installation from one drive to a new.

Comment: Still has Windows on it, but at this point, I've already stated the installation process. Thanks though.